# `systemd` error in Workbench instances created using custom container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am creating a Vertex AI Workbench instance from a custom container. Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113
RUN pip install ml_collections
```

Note that I have intentionally kept the Dockerfile short here because it will be enough to reproduce the issue.

The Workbench instance gets created but when I run `sudo shutdown now` from a terminal within the instance, it leads to:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Anything to mitigate this?

Comment: You can directly shutdown the instance using Server Console.Let me know if that helps.

Comment: We're doing `python .... && sudo shutdown now`. Manual shutdown is not preferred here.

Comment: Hi S. P , If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your container is getting into the interactive pip operation (where you need to type `Yes` to continue with the package install). This way, the container start becomes stuck and the container engine assumes that the container died.

Maybe a quick test would be replacing:

`RUN pip install ml_collections`

by

`RUN pip install -y ml_collections`

Comment: Thanks but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps for systemed error :

- Use below command to know the process name associated with PID 1 (the
  first process that runs on your system):

  `ps -p 1 -o comm=`
- It should show init or sysv or maybe something similar in the output.
  If you see init, your system is not using systemd and you can use the
  init commands as mentioned below.

| Systemd command | Sysvinit command |
| --- | --- |
| systemctl start service_name | service service_name start |
| systemctl stop service_name | service service_name stop |
| systemctl restart service_name | service service_name restart |
| systemctl status service_name | service service_name status |
| systemctl enable service_name | chkconfig service_name on |
| systemctl disable service_name | chkconfig service_name off |